# php key name change issue in associative array

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the keynames of the keys in my arraylist. Say, I have an array like the one below. I want to change "n" to "name" and "l" to "surname"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [n] => Amy
            [l] => Gonzalez
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [n] => Jeff
            [l] => Garcia
        )

)
```

This is my code. $data is where the array is stored and I get it dynamically.

```
$newkey = array('n'=>'name','l'=>'surname');
$count = count($data);
        $i=0;
        if($i<=$count){
            foreach( $data as &$item )
            {
                foreach( $newkey as $key => $replace )
                {
                    if (key_exists($key,$item))
                    {
                        $item[$replace] = $item[$key];
                        unset($item[$key]); 
                    }
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

This works for the last entry only. What am I doing wrong? My array may sometimes fetch several results, not only 2.

Comment: What are the variables `$i` and `$count` doing? Can you remove those and leave just the `foreach`?

Comment: first : remove the '&' before the $item variable

Comment: Initially I didn't but as the code worked only for the last entry, that is why I introduced those variables

Comment: @Miam84 no, use-by-reference is correct here.

Comment: @user2509780: Please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Yea, array_key_exists() is correct but I don't understand where I'm going wrong that I get the expected output only in my last entry

Comment: Simpler method posted, let PHP functions loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Not an answer persee but I need some space to post code*

I'm not sure what is wrong because this code works:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "n" => "a",
        "l" => "b"
    ),
    array(
        "n" => "a",
        "l" => "b"
    )
);
$newkey = array('n'=>'name','l'=>'surname');
foreach( $data as &$item )
{
    foreach( $newkey as $key => $replace )
    {
        if (key_exists($key,$item))
        {
            $item[$replace] = $item[$key];
            unset($item[$key]); 
        }
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "a" ["surname"]=> string(1) "b" } [1]=> &array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "a" ["surname"]=> string(1) "b" } }
```

Comment: Not having enough space to post code is not a valid reason to post it as an answer.

Comment: See this Meta question: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: @AmalMurali This is a reproducible test case. How would you suggest I post this code? Edit the original question? Seems a bit destructive to me. If you read the discussion you link you will see there are additional opinions, more practical and inline with my post.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Who said anything about editing the question? This is the same code the OP had  in the question (unless I'm missing something). You could have added a demo in http://eval.in and linked it in the comments. Anyway, this is a bit off-topic here, so if you want to discuss it further, please feel free to open a Meta discussion about it.

Comment: If you think it has added value you're welcome to link a demo to an offsite resource. _Lead by example_ don't just criticize (or do it on meta).

Comment: It is a severe limitation of SE that you can't post formatted code, much less large amounts of code, in a Comment (unless I'm overlooking something here). It would be nice to have a way to do Comments with large amounts of properly formatted code, possibly as an Answer-but-don't-count-this-as-an-"answer".

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, You don't the have right to use such swear word. Flagged your comment as **Rude / Offensive**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($data as &$array) {
    $array = array_combine(
        str_replace(array_keys($newkey), $newkey, array_keys($array)), $array);
}
```