# How can I rename some keys in a PHP array using another associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a data array ...

```
$data_array = array (
"old_name_of_item" => "Item One!"
);
```

... and a rename array ...

```
$rename_array = array (
"old_name_of_item" => "new_name_of_item"
);
```

... I would like to produce an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [new_name_of_item] => Item One!
)
```

I have written the following function, and while it works fine, I feel like I'm missing some features of PHP.

```
function rename_keys($array, $rename_array) {
foreach( $array as $original_key => $value) {
    foreach( $rename_array as $key => $replace ) {
        if ($original_key == $key) {
            $array[$replace] = $value;
            unset($array[$original_key]); 
        }
    }
}
return $array;
}
```

Does PHP offer built-in functions to help with this common problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a common problem, so there is no builtin.

Comment: @Sammitch: I've seen it twice today: [php key name change issue in associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150535/php-key-name-change-issue-in-associative-array/22150682#22150682)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to go through the array once:

```
function rename_keys($array, $rename_array) {
    foreach ( $rename_array as $original_key => $value ) {
        if (isset($array[$original_key])) {
            $array[$rename_array[$original_key]] = $array[$original_key];
            unset($array[$original_key]);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes, of course, that both arrays are correctly filled (unique values for the replacement keys).

Edit: only replace if a corresponding element exists in `$rename_array`.

Edit 2: only goes through `$rename_array`

Comment: You don't need to go through every value in $array, just every value in $rename_array which should be quicker

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? All keys in the same order, same keys in both arrays?

Comment: @James could you post an answer that shows how that would work?

Comment: @James, you're right! Martin, replacement keys should be unique. Updated answer to reflect both of these.

Comment: Oh, I see, so if there was a duplicate key, it wouldn't get renamed. I think we can deal with that. There shouldn't be duplicate keys. The major improvement in your answer is that, compared to my code, `isset()` replaces `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Actually, if you had `$array = array('a' => '1', 'b' => '2')` and `$rename_array = array('a' => 'c', 'b' => 'c')`, your resulting array would be `array('c' => '2')` and you would lose the first value.

Comment: That makes sense. Both `a` and `b` can't be renamed to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Second time today.  This one is easier:

```
$data_array = array_combine(
        str_replace(array_keys($rename_array), $rename_array, array_keys($data_array)), $data_array);
```

Comment: To answer my own question: this answer is much slower than the my answer. In the worst case (replace all keys), this took 10x longer for 100 elements, 1000X slower for 1000 elements, etc...